# Angular CORS request blocked

Tags: angular, express, cors

I am trying to connect my Angular app with a simple REST server on express. The server only sends `json` data in reply to request. To add `CORS` support, I used the `cors` module from npm. On the Angular app, I added `HttpHeaders` following the instructions from this question: [Angular CORS request blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352854/how-i-add-headers-to-http-get-or-http-post-in-typescript-and-angular-2?rq=1).

Here is my code in express where I set up the cors Options:
`

```
// async CORS setup delegation
function corsOptsDelegator(req, cb) {
    let opts = {},
        origin = req.header('Origin');
    if(imports.allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === 1) opts.origin = true;
    else opts.origin = false;
    opts.optionsSuccessStatus = 200;
    opts.methods = ['POST', 'GET']; // allowed methods
    opts.credentials = true; // for passing/setting cookie 
    opts.allowedHeaders = ['Content-Type', 'Accept', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin']; // restrict headers 
    opts.exposedHeaders = ['Accept', 'Content-Type']; // for exposing custom headers to clients; use for hash
    cb(null, opts);
}
`
```

Here's how I added it to the global `get` handler:

```
`
app.get('/', cors(corsOptsDelegator), (res, req, nxt) => {
    // only for adding cors on all requests
    nxt();
});
`
```

Here's how I set up the Angular service:

`

```
export class ContentGetterService {

  private root: string;
  private corsHeaders: HttpHeaders;
  //private contents: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.root = 'http://localhost:8888';
    this.corsHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:4200'
    });
    //this.contents = '';
   }

  getContent(subs: Array<string>): Observable<IContent> {
    return (() => {
      return this.http.get<IContent>( (() => {
        let r = this.root;
        subs.forEach((s, i, a) => {
          if(i === a.length-1) {
            r += s;
          }
          else {
            if(s !== '/') {
              r += s;
            }
          }
        });
        return r;
      })(), {
        headers: this.corsHeaders
      });

    })();
  }
  }
```

Browser Warning: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8888/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).`

Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

In case you are using angular-cli, you can use a proxy:

*proxy.conf.json*:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8888",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Will redirect all requests with `/api` prefix to localhost:8888 without any cors issue.

Offical docs:  https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Comment: This is a working solution but, I insist on using cors. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: I still get this issue even though I am using proxy like the way you mentioned above.

Comment: Worked for me. But for Angular versions >6 there's an updated documentation. https://angular.io/guide/build#proxy-multiple-entries

Comment: Please note that this only works on development environment, not in production

Comment: I cannot make it work in my dev environment. Where do I mention that this is a dev environment?

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, the problem on the client was due to the behavior of Firefox opting in to handle pre-flight CORS. Instead of using `GET` method,`OPTIONS` method was used. As it is evident from my code, I do not have any handler for handling `OPTIONS`. After some googling, I came across this post on github: [Express CORS middleware](https://gist.github.com/cuppster/2344435). Using this and making the following modifications to my client request headers, I was able to properly get it up and running. Here's the code:

CORS Middleware:

```
function myCors(req, res, nxt) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Language, Origin, User-Agent');
    if(req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.sendStatus(204);
    }
    else {
        nxt();
    }
}`
```

Mounting it to the app instance:
`app.use(myCors);`

On the Angular client side service:

```
this.corsHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
});
// ... adding it to the request
getContent(subs: Array<string>): Observable<IContent> {
return (() => {
  return this.http.get<IContent>( (() => {
    let r = this.root;
    subs.forEach((s, i, a) => {
      if(i === a.length-1) {
        r += s;
      }
      else {
        if(s !== '/') {
          r += s;
        }
      }
    });
    return r;
  })(), {
    headers: this.corsHeaders
  });
 
})();
}
```

Thanks everyone for their time and efforts.

**Edit**

Thanks to @neutrino for pointing out that adding the `Access-Control-*` headers on the request makes no sense (and has no effect).

Comment: Isn't using `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as a request header incorrect? I believe that header should only be used in the server response. I think you could remove the request header code entirely and as long as the server returns the correct headers it should still work correctly.

Comment: @neutrino Thanks for pointing it out. Now I understand it better to know it's just wrong!

Answer (score 4):

In development environment(localhost),you can do it easily without following any of these hard steps.You can simply download https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/ if you are using firefox and i think there must be an extension for chrome also.After downloading it will come to the firefox menubar and then you can click it to activate it,thats all you can now access to all apis as it automatically sends header with all requests.For production environment you have to configure it from your server by adding access-control-allow-origin to * (all)

Comment: Yes, there is somethin similar for Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with Angular CLI, NPM, Spring Data JPA and Tomcat 9, I finally found a solution to communicate between a frontend webapp (Angular) and backend webapp (Spring Data JPA) running on an application server (Tomcat).

**In development environment:**

The annotation `@CrossOrigin("localhost:4200")` in your Spring DAO repository is just fine if you running `ng serve` on default port 4200.

```java
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
public interface ConfigRepository extends JpaRepository<Config, String> {
    
}
```

**In production environment:**

If your application is running on a productive server, you have to modify your `web.xml` and add a (e.g.) build-in CORS filter to allow access to other resources as the origin.

```xml
<!-- ==================== CORS Filter Definition ====================== -->

<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8080</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Access-Control-Allow-Origin</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The difference to the template from [Tomcat 9 CORS Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) is to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `cors.allowed.header` and set an actual allowed origin in `cors.allowed.origins` e.g. `http://localhost:8080`.

So, there is no need to specify explicit headers to an HTTP request. Thanks to @Neutrino.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and manage yourself according to your structure.

```
app.use(
    cors({ 
        origin: http://localhost:4200, 
        methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
        allowedHeaders: [
            'Content-Type', 
            'Authorization', 
            'Origin', 
            'x-access-token', 
            'XSRF-TOKEN'
        ], 
        preflightContinue: false 
    })
);

app.get('/', (res, req, nxt) => {
    // only for adding cors on all requests
    nxt();
});
```

**On Angular Side**

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  this.root = 'http://localhost:8888';  //remove
  this.corsHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '/' .  // edit 
  });
  //this.contents = '';
 }
```

and use `<base>` index.html

Comment: I modified according to ur suggestions. Still same error. And, I am not sure what u mean by `<base>` index.html

Comment: Change the `<base>` `href` to what?

Comment: <base href="/">

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you can create a proxy for your Angular app. Go to your Angular project directory and under the src folder, create a file named `proxy.config.json`.

**On proxy.config.json**

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3010",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

`http://localhost:3010` is the backend service.

Then in the `package.json` file, under the `scripts` add this line `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",` his will set up a proxy from your app to your backend service.

Now, when you make any API calls, you don’t need to include this part: `http://localhost:3010`
For example, instead of calling `http://localhost:3010/api/myapp`, now you can use `/api/myapp`

Also before test ,restart the serve again.

Answer (score -1):

Allow Server side that you hit from angular JS, in that case you need to allow `http://localhost:8888/` because that is your server side URL, angular run on `http://localhost:4200`. please check the Http. then it work

Comment: I believe this is what u meant: 
`this.corsHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8888'
    });`

Tried this with the same error unfortunately.

Comment: if you use `secure: false`, then no need use cors middleware to check, then remove that code also. it means remove the cors feature from your angular. i think that one is not good idea.

Comment: I agree that turning off cors is a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, because, we always allow server side from client side. not client side.

Comment: Please look this URL for better understanding https://github.com/chandan4u/Node-JS-Security-Implementation/blob/master/server.js

Comment: `app.use(cors({
    origin: http://localhost:4200,
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Origin', 'x-access-token', 'XSRF-TOKEN'],
    preflightContinue: false
}));`

Comment: you also need to allow API URL in Angular to access Node JS API

Comment: Following the link, I modified my `cors` implementation and used the one u provided. I replaced `origin: ['http://localhost:4200']`. I am still getting the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170632/discussion-between-chandan-kumar-and-abrar-hossain).

Comment: Use this code and manage ur self according to ur structure.
`app.use(cors({ origin: http://localhost:4200, methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE', allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Origin', 'x-access-token', 'XSRF-TOKEN'], preflightContinue: false }));`

`app.get('/', (res, req, nxt) => {
    // only for adding cors on all requests
    nxt();
});`

On Angular Side