# origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy in Angular7

Tags: angular

I want to use of http://5.160.2.148:8091/api/trainTicketing/city/findAll rest for get cities in my angular project.
I used version 7.2.15 of angular in my project.
when get this url with httpClient throw following error :

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://5.160.2.148:8091/api/trainTicketing/city/findAll' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

While at work correctly when enter url in browser and postman.

why ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular CORS request blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237881/angular-cors-request-blocked)

Comment: It may sound weird  but I didn't have to change anything on server side. There were two branch of angular ui project, on one it was working on another it wasn't. I'm yet to find the conclusive answer.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Solution 1 - you need to change your backend to accept your incoming requests

Solution 2 - using Angular proxy [see here](https://medium.com/@spencerfeng/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d)

> Please note this is only for `ng serve`, you can't use proxy in `ng build`

Solution 3 - **IF** your backend accepts requests from a wildcard domanin like `*.mydomain.example` then you can edit your `hosts` file and add `127.0.0.1 local.mydomain.example` in there, then in your browser instead of `localhost:4200` enter `local.mydomain.example:4200`

Note: the reason it's working via postman is postman doesn't send preflight requests while your browser does.

Comment: I know it's been a while since your answer, but could you please elaborate on Solution 1? I have the same error "bla bla bla  has been blocked by CORS policy..."

Answer (score 49):

## For .NET CORE 3.1

I was using **https redirection** just before adding **cors middleware** and able to fix the issue by changing order of them

*What i mean is:*

**change this:**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

      ...
        
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();  

        app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());

      ...

     }
```

**to this:**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

      ...
        
        app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());

        app.UseHttpsRedirection(); 

      ...

     }
```

By the way, allowing requests from any origins and methods may not be a good idea for production stage, you should write your own cors policies at production.

Comment: This worked for me. I changed the order and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: This did NOT work for me!  Check the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#middleware-order for proper order.  I believe getting the proper order solved my issue.  Use order as follows: ExceptionHandler/ Hsts / HttpsRedirection / StaticFiles / CookiePolicy / Routing / RequestLocalization / Cors / Authentication / Authorization / Session / ResponseCompression / ResponseCaching / ...custom... / Endpoint

Answer (score 41):

if You use spring boot , you should add origin link in the @CrossOrigin annotation

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@GetMapping("/yourPath")
```

You can find detailed instruction in the https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: @CamiloCasadiego it applies to what I'm looking for :)

Thanks for this!

Answer (score 10):

The solution needs to add these headers to the server response.

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT'
```

If you have access to the server, you can add them and this will solve your problem

**OR**

You can try concatentaing this in front of the url:

```
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/
```

Answer (score 10):

For temporary testing during development we can disable it by opening chrome with disabled web security like this.

Open command line terminal and go to folder where chrome is installed i.e. C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application

Enter this command:

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

A new browser window will open with disabled web security. Use it only for testing your app.

Comment: For some reason, I got a bunch of "unexpected error"s when I tried this :|

Answer (score 9):

You are all good at Angular side even postman not raise the cors policy issue.
This type of issue is solved at back-end side in major cases.

If you are using Spring Boot, then you can avoid this issue by placing this annotation at your controller class or at any particular method.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
```

In case of global configuration with Spring Boot configure the following two classes:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api1/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api2/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api3/**").permitAll()
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry corsRegistry) {
        corsRegistry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                    .allowedMethods("*")
                    .maxAge(3600L)
                    .allowedHeaders("*")
                    .exposedHeaders("Authorization")
                    .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree with @shyam. It's the backend (rest API server) issue to solve, not Angular front end. I am having the same issue, and fixing the backend configuration is the correct way.

Answer (score 7):

Startup.cs in WebAPI.

```
app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin());
```

In ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddCors(c =>  
{  
    c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options => options.AllowAnyOrigin());  
});
```

In Controller:

```
[HttpGet]  
     [Route("GetAllAuthor")]  
     [EnableCors("AllowOrigin")]
```

Answer (score 6):

Follow these steps

1. Add cors dependency. type the following in cli inside your project directory

> `npm install --save cors`

2. Include the module inside your project

> `var cors = require('cors');`

3. Finally use it as a middleware.

> `app.use(cors());`

Comment: is this solution on angular's end? or a node.js server?

Comment: the solution is in node.js server

Answer (score 5):

If your project is .net Core 3.1 API project.

update your Startup.cs in your .net core project to:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:53135",
                                    "http://localhost:4200"
                                    )
                                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                                    .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });
        services.AddDbContext<CIVDataContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CIVDatabaseConnection")));
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

       
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me with .netcore 3.1 and angular 12

Comment: Thanks @MJ X, I have done one mistake. I have placed UseCors() at the end. So that it's not working

Answer (score 3):

For `nodejs` use the below code

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a class and add the below configuration in the spring boot application.

```
    package com.myapp.springboot.configs;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
    
    @Configuration
    public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/*").
            allowedOrigins("*").
            allowedMethods("*").
            allowedHeaders("*").
            allowCredentials(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1:
Create a class WebMvcConfig and extend it as shown from the ***WebMvcConfiguration*** and override **addCorsMappings** method.

2:
Most importantly don't forget to make it **@Configuration** annotation because it should be loaded with Main Spring class to allow Cross-Origin.

```
  @Configuration
    public class WebMvcCofig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/*")
                    .allowedOrigins("*")
                    .allowedMethods("*")
                    .allowedHeaders("*")
                    .allowCredentials(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I Tried adding the below statement on my API on the express server and it worked with Angular8.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET , PUT , POST , DELETE");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, x-requested-with");
    next(); // Important
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the solutions given above and worked while using nodejs backend but unfortunately while working with python it dint work, so I ended up installing a plugin [Allow CORS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf), atleast this plugin helped

Answer (score 2):

Add @CrossOrigin("*") Annoations on your controller class like below

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class UserController {
  @Autowired
  UserService userService;

  @PostMapping("/user")
  public boolean createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    return userService.createUser(user);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **spring-boot** for server side coding then please add a **servlet filter** and add the following code of your spring-boot application. It should work. Adding `"Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*"` is mandatory. Creation of **proxy.conf.json** is not needed.

```
    @Component
@Order(1)
public class MyProjectFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PATCH,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case using **Angular and Spring Boot** I solved that issue in my SecurityConfig:

```
http.csrf().disable().cors().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/register")
            .anonymous()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

Or replace that line to:

```
http.csrf().disable().cors().and()
```

And other test option is **to delete dependency** from pom.xml and other code depend on it. It's like turn off security from Spring:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
     <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Spring boot 2 you can add CrossOrigin annotation in the controller class

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
```

it worked for me !

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to handle the issue of CORs in spring boot, the easiest way is to just put the @CrossOrigin annotation on top of the Controller may be in your ..resource java file. Try

`@CrossOrigin(origins= {"*"}, maxAge = 4800, allowCredentials = "false"    @RestController`

for more info read spring boot CORs docs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular with Dotnet Core:

On class Startup.cs

On method ConfigureServices add:

```
services.AddCors();
```

On method Configure add

```
app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200"));
```

Answer (score 1):

- If you are using spring boot application then just add @CrossOrigin
  in your Controller and import the statement import
  org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;  that set and
  run the application again

Answer (score 1):

> Normal REST API IN JAVA CROS POLICY

```
@GET
@Path("getsample")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getOptions() {
       Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
       // map.put("response",res); 
        map.put("name","Ajay");
         map.put("id","20");
         map.put("clg", "SLICA");
     
  return Response.ok()
    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS")
    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With")
    .entity(map)    
    .build();
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If by Any chance you are using fireBase as a dataBase you need to add ".json" to the end of the link, this solved the issue for me

cors error: https://uar-test-bd448-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/rules

NO ERROR: https://uar-test-bd448-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/rules.**json**

Answer (score 1):

## Nestjs

```
app.enableCors({ origin: "*" });
```

Allows any origin. I recommend only allowing this in development mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one mapping annotation, for example using

`@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")`

at the top of the class and

`@GetMapping("/employees")`

above the method and so on, then you don't need to write the code below for each of the method; writing this the top of your class will be enough:

`@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")`

Answer (score 1):

**My error**
`@CrossOrigin(origins = "/http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)`.

**Fixed by removing a slash**
`@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33176439)

Comment: Yes got it, But i thought people who were carrying headache bcs f this, thats why posted this, thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my case I saw the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:5000/graphql' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, brave, chrome-untrusted, https.
```

Make sure to include a protocol (http or https) in your urls.

```
const uri = 'http://localhost:5000/graphql'; //
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using node as a backend you can use this. Just add these lines on the server.js "API" side in Node.js, before that make sure to install "cors"

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Answer (score 0):

if using Nodejs(Back-End) with application angular install the cors in NodeJs
npm install --save cors

var cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/getuser' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Step 1: You have to add AuthInterceptor in the Frontend Part

File auth.interceptor.ts->

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { LoginService } from "./login.service";


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private loginservice: LoginService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {


        const token = this.loginservice.getToken();

        console.log("interceptor", token);

        if (token != null) {
            console.log("hello");

            req = req.clone(
                {
                    setHeaders: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                    }
                }
            )
        }
        return next.handle(req);

    }

}
```

Then save and run again. If the same problem is occurred so doing the next step

If you are using Spring Boot in Backend so MySecurityConfig file contains configure method.
configure Method->

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .cors().disbale()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/token")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(entrypoint)
            ;
        
        
    // if the problem not solve so change .cors().disable() -> .cors()   only   

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Spring Boot 2.7.0**

Add crossorigin annotation in Controller class like that -

```
package com.test.emp.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.test.emp.entity.Employee;
import com.test.emp.service.EmployeeService;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*") 
public class MyController {
    
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;
    
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return "this is home page";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/add-employee")
    public Employee addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        return this.employeeService.addEmployee(employee);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/all-employee")
    public List<Employee> allEmployee() {
        return this.employeeService.getAllEmployee();
    }

}
```

Note - I'm using star for all type of url, If you want access any particular url the mention like this-

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9090/")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Need Proper Ordering

```
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthTokenMiddleware();
```

Answer (score -1):

if You're using Springboot you can add following to the main class.
following is what worked for me.

```
@Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200",  "<other urls>")); //Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type",
                "Accept", "Jwt-Token", "Authorization", "Origin, Accept", "X-Requested-With",
                "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
        corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Jwt-Token", "Authorization",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return new CorsFilter(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**For Spring Boot 2.7.9**

Add @CrossOrigin dependency In your controller class
as an example:

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")

[image]