# Angular http (get) request failed

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript

I want to send a value and in the backend modify it and send it again, I did this:

Back end in Java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/renueva", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public String refreshToken (HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        String auth = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        return auth.toUpperCase();
    }
```

Front end in Angular:

```
refreshToken(): Observable<string>{
  return this.http.get<string>("localhost:8080/renueva")
}
```

in other component:

```
this.auth.refreshToken().subscribe(data => console.log('en el inter 2' + data));
```

On the console it shows me:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [origin-http-localhost4200-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-in-angular7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56328474/origin-http-localhost4200-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-in-angular7)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy in Angular7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56328474/origin-http-localhost4200-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-in-angular7)

Comment: @mentallurg nop

Comment: What does it mean? You have changed your backend to accept CORS requests and it still rejects?

Comment: Yes, I do not know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @mentallurg now, the error is Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: Now you have changed the question completely. There is nothing more about port 4200 and CORS. Now you have completely different question.

Comment: Try adding the protocol to the request. ‘this.http.get<string>(‘http://localhost:8080/renueva’)‘

Comment: @Japsz doesn't work :(

Comment: where are you setting the authorization header?

Comment: Try `return this.http.get<string>("http://localhost:8080/renueva")`