# Okta Api Access to fetch at "okta-api-url' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, cors, preflight

getting given below error while trying to access the OKTA api could you please suggest the possible solution, in Angular

```
 Access to fetch at 'https://dev-99322141.okta.com/api/v1/authn' from origin
 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't 
pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to 
fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

config/my-app-config.ts

```
export default {
    oidc: {
        clientId: '<client id which is get from OKTA API>',
        issuer: 'https://dev-<numbers>.okta.com/oauth2/default',
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/login/callback',
        scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email']
    }
}
```

login.component.ts

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  oktaSignIn: any;

  constructor(private oktaAuthService: OktaAuthService) { 

    this.oktaSignIn = new OktaSignIn({
      logo:'assets/images/logo.png',
      baseUrl: myAppConfig.oidc.issuer.split('/oauth2')[0],
      clientId: myAppConfig.oidc.clientId,
      redirectUri: myAppConfig.oidc.redirectUri,
      authParams: {
        pkce: true,
        issuer: myAppConfig.oidc.issuer,
        scopes: myAppConfig.oidc.scopes
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.oktaSignIn.remove(); // remove if any previous elements over there

    this.oktaSignIn.renderEl({
      el: '#okta-sign-in-widget'}, // this name shouldb e same as dive tag id in login.component.html
      (response) =>  {
        if(response.status === 'SUCCESS') {
          this.oktaAuthService.signInWithRedirect();
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        throw error;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

what could be the the possible solution to allow cors to access the Okta URL, https://dev-99322141.okta.com/api/v1/authn by http://localhost:4200

Comment: I'm afraid that cors cannot be fixed in your angular app, but you'll have to create a proxy for this purpose. A bunch of others people already provide help for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56328576/11135174

Comment: Does this answer your question? [origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy in Angular7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56328474/origin-http-localhost4200-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-in-angular7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I problem can be solved in OKTA configurations regarding headers or strict font. The API expects information in the header that you do not send. Or you forgot you sent it.