# Angular - Sample Down failed to load response data

Tags: angular

In my Angular-12, I tried to load Sample download before Excel import for users to see how the pattern of the download should be:

service:

```
downloadSample(): any {
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/sample_download/countries.xlsx', {responseType: 'blob'});
}
```

compoent:

```
downloadSample() {
  this.countriesService.downloadSample().subscribe((response: any) => { //when you use stricter type checking
    let blob:any = new Blob([response], { type: 'text/json; charset=utf-8' });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    fileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'countries.json');
    Swal.fire({
      position: 'center',
      icon: 'success',
      title: 'Sample File downloaded successfully',
      showConfirmButton: true,
      timer: 5000
    });
  }),
  Swal.fire({
    position: 'center',
    icon: 'error',
    title: 'Sample File downloaded Failed',
    showConfirmButton: true,
    timer: 5000
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<h5> Download the sample format of Excel sheet. <input type="button" (click)="downloadSample()" value="Download Excel Template"/></h5>
```

I got this error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/sample_download/countries.xlsx' from origin
'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

"Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/sample_download/countries.xlsx: 0 Unknown Error"
message: "Unknown Error"

How do I resolve these?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56328474/origin-http-localhost4200-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-in-angular7

Answer (score 0):

Could be fixed from backend side by whitelisting front end ports, most probably 4200.

Comment: most likely, it goes something like this: 

for django, in the settings file, CORS_ALLOW_WHITELIST = (portnumber1, portnumber2) should be added.