# Convert Curl request to Angular request

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have a problem with this CURL request. It works fine if I send it over terminal but when I convert it to Angular HTTP Client call it doesn't work.

Curl:

```
curl --location --request PUT '<some_url>' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "status": "CONFIRMED"
}'
```

Angular:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  .set('Accept', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

const b = {
  status: 'CONFIRMED'
};

return this.http.put(some_url, b, { headers });
```

Error:
Access to <some_url> from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
      }),
    };
const b = {
  status: 'CONFIRMED'
};
return this.http<any>(some_url, b,httpOptions)
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
```

use a proxy.config.json file

```
 {
      "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://backendurl",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true
      }
    }
```

add the proxy configuration the angular.json under the serve->options :

```
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
      "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json" // add this ligne
    },
```

Comment: `
const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
      }),
    };
`
Aren't necessary, except from this, everything will work fine but.

Answer (score 0):

```
return this.http.put(some_url, body);
```

Should work.

Comment: It doesn't: has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.

Comment: OK, that's another problem. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237881/angular-cors-request-blocked/50242631

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to call `subscribe()` after the `put()`, otherwise the request won't be executed at all.

Comment: I am doing this

Comment: Then you should elaborate on the term "doesn't work".