# CORS policy error with front end and back end all on Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, cors

We have an Angular web application running on Azure.  The backend is Dot Net Core 3.1.  The Authentication is done through Azure AD.  What is happening is the following steps

1. User logs into the web site and navigates to a page.  Everything is working as expected
2. The user logs out, but does not close the tab.  The Logout screen is shown as expected
3. The user opens a new tab and navigates to the web site
4. The user is NOT prompted for a login and when the user navigates to page they get error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/2aa666ca-a53c-4274-bfcc-41b83867d22a/oauth2/authorize?client_id=794424bb-0ad2-41f8-b007-b71ed576b793&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.azurewebsites.net%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637782164067215548.NzQ4MWQxNjgtYjdlZS00OTlmLWIwYzctM2NhZWRkZjdhMTZiYzdmNjljOTEtNTk3OS00NDlhLWEzZjgtODZkN2YyZDZmYzlh&state=CfDJ8IE9b1M0cDdJqtQPg1_KxRR0vlYAN1zOfKzhpzhdzqvcX_XGygV8nincOzoVYDPPyZWnbh5SrGMDZhQfmUDlO4wQ41v_7Q_gJCUHftetejZZQZTS7Uhn-IVBRysh36hvldRY2pxcZBKCQHLYkKMnR2my9R0TqsaqEAI4gGNUUHwa8fJnv4xj0lkMJq_DORhJS4AwLMhtQWGvuIp0gzQ_cGR0gjGZvMRMTaBZunGBDexThOzzbAyQJTCJuNxUUB_tvAm0cFEVWb3lTPYRgk1ARnagmg7a6GDFrCnXT7vT_3VJjUyMzrazbt1xeRtrs1AdlUIX1fnnFsGZPGUBA3kYvzTyEgVkm97FGBTPgeGZAP3W&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0' (redirected from 'https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/api/profileTypes?_=1642619606751') from origin 'https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

If the user refreshes the page, then they are forced to login and everything begins working again

I have tried adding in CORS as directed on other questions and other websites as follows

In the ConfigureService function of the startup.cs  The following code is present

```
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder
                .WithOrigins(new[] { "http://YOUR_FRONTEND_ORIGIN" })
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials();
        }));
```

In the Configure function of the startup.cs is the following code

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

I am confused as to why CORs would even come into play as everything is on the same Azure subscription, but I added the above code and it does not change anything.  Searching the internet give mainly the same or similar implementations as above.

I am not sure how to proceed or even what questions to ask, so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is an HTTP-header based mechanism which basically allows server to indicate any  origins  other than its original url or scheme or domain or port .But cors settings may also vary from different browsers which may cause this error.

In case of Azure App Service it sets  “AppServiceAuthSession” cookie for authenticated session with browser. The web application may use XMLHttpRequest / AJAX request inside the app and the request sent may contain the AppServiceAuthSession cookie. When this cookie is still present in the browser and the web page pointing to the page of app may not be the original url and which might be the possible cause of error.When this cookie is not present in the request, Azure App Service will redirect the request to Azure AD for login that is why when you referesh it, it works.

If the browser is  enabled with cors ,it makes a pre-flight cors check to the specified url  and gets the access-control-allow-origin headers, we can modify this headers accordingly,if origin restriction is not required.

Try to insert the http protocol present in the asp.net Web Api backend, in the Web.config between the <system.webServer> </ system.webServer> tags,

*Example:*

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

and  you can try  enable access to all origins from [browser settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54212220/how-to-fix-access-to-xmlhttprequest-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-redirect-i) .

Please check this reference [access to xmlhttprequest has been blocked by cors policy Code Example (codegrepper.com)](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/access+to+xmlhttprequest+has+been+blocked+by+cors+policy) if you can enable credentails to true and by using cors variable to use in app.use(cors).

**References:**

1. [Cross-origin XMLHttpRequest - Chrome Developers](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/xhr/)
2. [express - Angular CORS request blocked - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237881/angular-cors-request-blocked)