# Is there a way to block CORS policy when a function runs on different page that opened through anchor tag (with _blank)?

Tags: angular, typescript, window

I am using window.open() to open any url on a new window. (additionally i am replacing the url with location.href, "this is just to let you understand what i am trying to do")

```
this.newChildWindow =
              window.open(
                url, "_blank", `width="${altScreen.availWidth}", height="${altScreen.availHeight}"`
              );
```

So my question is i want to run a session timeout on that newly opened window, can i do that?
for now i am trying to see if i can execute any function only on that page, but its giving CORS error/ Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:4200" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

so how to get past that CORS policy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular CORS request blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237881/angular-cors-request-blocked)

Comment: You're hitting some of the Same-Origin Policy's restrictions on cross-origin object access, but this has got nothing to do with the CORS protocol.

Comment: yes @jub0bs it was something different, i solved that with `chrome.exe --disable-web-security` command as for now i'm doing this on dev environment (even then i still want to share resources on cross origin so LOL, i am still not sure if it is part of cors or not regardless i got the answer), thanks for pointing that out. And @Sumesh TG thanks for replying, as i was working on nodejs previously i thought it had something to do with CORS protocol, but anyway thanks for the refferences guys  : )