Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8080' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy
`I was trying to make a car rental application using Spring Boot and Angular, but I couldn't get my carPost function to work. If I understand correctly, the problem is that my backend system is not allowing the request from my frontend system. I believe that this is caused by the jwt authentication system, but I am not completely sure. I apologize for asking for help for a recurring error despite reviewing multiple forum posts; my current level of proficiency on the topic is hindering my ability to solve it independently.
postCar(carDto: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`${BASIC_URL}/api/admin/car`, carDto, {
        headers: this.createAuthorizationHeader()
    });
}

createAuthorizationHeader(): HttpHeaders {
    let authHeaders: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    return authHeaders.set(
        'Authorization',
        'Bearer ' + StorageService.getToken()
    );
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    private final UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests(request ->
                        request.antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                                .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority(UserRole.ADMIN.name())
                                .antMatchers("/api/customer/**").hasAnyAuthority(UserRole.CUSTOMER.name())
                                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(manager ->
                        manager.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService.userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }
}

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RequestMapping("/api/admin")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AdminController {
    private final AdminService adminService;

    @PostMapping("/car")
    public ResponseEntity<?> postCar(@ModelAttribute CarDto carDto) throws IOException {
        boolean success = adminService.postCar(carDto);

        if (success) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
    }
}


Does this answer your question? CORS Angular and SpringBoot - request blocked

Please do some search before posting  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237881/angular-cors-request-blocked

Does this answer your question? Angular CORS request blocked
