# Angular 8 - How to add to my request header a X-Auth-Token?

Tags: javascript, authentication, request

I'm working in the integration of a new API endpoint. As a security measure the endpoint expects
in the post request headers:

```
 'x-client-key': 'FRONTEND'
```

I have been looking around the net , but can't seem to find how to implement in my particular case.

How could I add this in my request?

```
  getMagic(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http
        .post(environment.serverUrl + this.getApiEndPoint() + 'get-magic', data)
        .subscribe(
          (response: any) => {
            resolve(response);
          },
          (err) => {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
          }
        );
    });
  }
```

This is what I've tried but doesn't work...

```
    const headers = new Headers().set('Content-Type', 'application/json').set('x-client-key',  'FRONTEND_CLIENT_KEY ');

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http
        .post(environment.serverUrl + this.getApiEndPoint() + 'get-geocoding', data, { headers: headers })
        .subscribe(
          (response: any) => {
            resolve(response);
          },
          (err) => {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
          }
        );
    });
  }
```

I tried also

```
const headers = new Headers();
headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.set('x-client-key',  'FRONTEND_CLIENT_KEY ');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're using Angular, not sure which version, so I'll write a solution for pre-7 and post-7 Angular:

Angular 6 or below:

```js
const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
  'x-client-key': 'your key'
}

const requestOptions = {
  headers: new Headers(headers),
};

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.http
    .post(environment.serverUrl + this.getApiEndPoint() + 'get-geocoding', data, requestOptions)
    .subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        resolve(response);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
      }
    );
});
```

Angular 7 or later: replace the class `Headers` with a class `HttpHeaders`, [docs here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders).

First, import the `HttpHeaders` class:

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

And then refactor your code into:

```js
const requestOptions = {                                                                                                                                                                                 
  headers: new HttpHeaders(headers), 
};
```

Solution originally taken [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352854/how-i-add-headers-to-http-get-or-http-post-in-typescript-and-angular-2).

Comment: I have tried the proposed approach, but it doesn't seem to work...
on angular 8 HttpHeaders is not working, do I have to add a new library or it is part of angular core? I get Cannot find name 'HttpHeaders'

Comment: @Herzlin I have updated the answer with HttpHeaders docs link & an import statement. Please, try now.

Comment: I have imported it and it works. thanks for the kind assistance @Zlatan.