# Using RapidAPI with Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to use SkyScanner API from Rapidapi with Angular to search for flight prices. here is my code

```
 headers = new Headers();
    url:string;
    
constructor(private _http:HttpClient,) {
this.headers.append('X-RapidAPI-Key', 'MY-KEY');
this.url = 'https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/browseroutes/v1.0/IE/EUR/en-GB/{here should be other parameters like destination}' }
```

I am passing from,to,day,month and year from inputs

```
getFlightDetail(from,to,day,month,year) : Observable<Iflight>{
  return this._http.get<Iflight>(this.url+this.headers)
  .pipe(
    tap(data => console.log('flightData/error' + JSON.stringify(data))
    ),
    catchError(this.handlerError)
  );
}
```

the issue is when I ran the app I got

> 401 Unauthorized

Comment: Hi Omar, welcome to stackoverflow! You should double check how you are setting your http headers in your get call. It looks like you are adding them (string concatenation) to your url. Check out this link and see if it helps you out:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352854/how-i-add-headers-to-http-get-or-http-post-in-typescript-and-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

`x-rapidapi-host` header is missing. You also need to add two custom headers if you're using RapidAPI, `x-rapidapi-key` and `x-rapidapi-host`

Also, I'm assuming you're already subscribed to Skyscanner API.